# Is it possible to realize the Moebius strip as a linear group orbit?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, rt.representation-theory, gt.geometric-topology, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

On MSE this got 5 upvotes but no answers not even a comment so I figured it was time to cross-post it on MO:

Is the Moebius strip a linear group orbit? In other words:

**Does there exists a Lie group $ G $ a representation $ \pi: G \to \operatorname{Aut}(V) $ and a vector $ v \in V $ such that the orbit
$$
\mathcal{O}_v=\{ \pi(g)v: g\in G  \} 
$$
is diffeomorphic to the Moebius strip?**

My thoughts so far:

The only two obstructions I know for being a linear group orbit is that the manifold (1) must be smooth homogeneous (shown below for the the group $ \operatorname{SE}_2 $) and (2) must be a vector bundle over a compact Riemannian homogeneous manifold (here the base is the circle $ S^1 $).

The Moebius strip is homogeneous for the special Euclidean group of the plane
$$
\operatorname{SE}_2= \left \{ \
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & x \\
-b & a & y \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix} : a^2+b^2=1 \right \}.
$$
There is a connected group $ V $ of translations up each vertical line
$$
V= \left \{ \ 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & y \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix} : y \in \mathbb{R} \right \}.
$$
Now if we include the rotation by 180 degrees
$$
\tau:=\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
then $ \langle V, \tau \rangle$ has two connected components and
$$
\operatorname{SE}_2/\langle V, \tau \rangle
$$
is the Moebius strip.

Comment: Your previous related question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/410275/is-the-moebius-strip-riemannian-homogeneous

Comment: This is almost the same as the previous question Sam Hopkins links to.   The Moebius band can be thought of as the space of affine $1$-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb R^2$, i.e. the space of "infinite lines in the Euclidean plane".   From this point of view, the group of Euclidean symmetries acts transitively.  So yes, it's a group orbit.

Comment: @RyanBudney Although Moebius band is certainly an orbit for a linear group, $ SE_2 $, that does not make it a linear group orbit (bad terminology :( I got it from https://mathoverflow.net/questions/206618/how-bad-can-pi-1-of-a-linear-group-orbit-be). To see the distinction, note that Klein bottle is the orbit of a group action of  $ SE_2 $ but Klein bottle cannot be a linear group orbit since its fundamental group does not have a finite commutator subgroup (see same linked question). The distinction:  orbit of generic smooth group action vs orbit of linear group action on a vector space

Comment: You need to define your terminology.  People can't answer your question if they don't know what you are asking. Is $V$ supposed to be a vector space, is that what you mean by "linear group orbit"?

Comment: The first sentence of my question defines exactly what a linear group orbit is but it was a huge oversight on my part not to say that that was what I was defining. My apologies. I will edit it now adding the preamble "Is the Moebius strip a linear group orbit? In other words:" And yes $ V $ is a vector space that is why the question said "a vector $ v \in V $ "

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira Could you explain how $SE_2$ acts on a Klein bottle? I am not seeing it, and I am curious.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer The same way a point on the Moebius strip is an affine line in the plane a point on the Klein bottle is a set of all the lines parallel to some affine line in the plane and an integer distance apart. In particular, the same way that the subgroup $ <V,\tau> $ above is the stabilizer of the y axis the subgroup $ <V,\tau,b> $ is the stabilizer of the set of all vertical lines with integer x intercept (here $ b $ just translates by 1 in the x direction). More details in my post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4316503/is-it-possible-to-realize-the-klein-bottle-as-a-linear-gro

Comment: This idea is not original and I found it in this answer by Moishe Kohan https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3233411/is-every-compact-solvmanifold-the-quotient-of-a-simply-connected-solvable-lie-gr It seems that it was already  known to Mostow 1950 that Klein bottle was homogeneous for a Lie group as mentioned by Montgomery in https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1950-001-04/S0002-9939-1950-0037311-6/S0002-9939-1950-0037311-6.pdf

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes.  Here is one way:  Consider standard $\mathbb{R}^3$ endowed with the Lorentzian quadratic form $Q = x^2+y^2-z^2$, and let $G\simeq\mathrm{O}(2,1)\subset\mathrm{GL}(3,\mathbb{R})$ be the symmetry group of $Q$.  Then $G$ preserves the hyperboloid $H$ of $1$-sheet given by the level set $Q=1$, which is diffeomorphic to a cylinder.  Consider the quotient of $H$ by $\mathbb{Z}_2$ defined by identifying $v\in H\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ with $-v$.  This abstract quotient is a smooth Möbius strip.

This quotient can be identified as a linear group orbit as follows:  Let $V = S^2(\mathbb{R}^3)\simeq \mathbb{R}^6$ and consider the smooth mapping $\sigma:\mathbb{R}^3\to V$ given by $\sigma(v) = v^2$ for $v\in\mathbb{R}^3$.  Then $\sigma$ is a $2$-to-$1$ immersion except at the origin.  The action of $G$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$ extends equivariantly to a representation $\rho:G\to \mathrm{Aut}(V)$ such that $\rho(g)(v^2) = \rho\bigl(\sigma(v)\bigr)=\sigma(g v)= (gv)^2$.  It follows that $\sigma(H)\subset S^2(\mathbb{R}^3)\simeq\mathbb{R}^6$, which is a Möbius strip, is a linear group orbit under the representation $\rho$.

Note that the representation of $G$ on $S^2(\mathbb{R}^3)\simeq\mathbb{R}^6$ is actually reducible as the direct sum of a trivial $\mathbb{R}$ and an irreducible $\mathbb{R}^5$.  Projecting everything into the $\mathbb{R}^5$ factor, one obtains a representation of $G$ on $\mathbb{R}^5$ that has a Möbius strip as a $G$-orbit.

Comment: Let $D$ be one of the components of a hyperboloid of $2$-sheets in your same $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then we can think of $D$ as the hyperbolic plane, and we can identify $H/\langle \pm 1 \rangle$ as the space of lines in $D$. So one way to describe your construction is "the symmetry group of the hyperbolic plane acts on the set of lines in the hyperbolic plane".

Comment: @DavidESpeyer:  Yes, but the whole point is to represent the space of lines as a group orbit of a point in a representation of the group, not just to identify it as a homogeneous space.

Comment: Of course! On my december 8th question "Moebius strip Riemannian homogeneous?" (its not) Ian Agol commented that it is Lorentzian homogeneous as space of lines in the hyperbolic plane. That seemed important but I wasn't smart enough to put it all together. This is a beautiful flowing answer thanks so much. I wonder if this extends to a general fact that every pseudo Riemannian homogeneous manifold is a linear group orbit? At least every Riemannian homogeneous manifold is a linear group orbit basically bc isometry group is compact then Mostow-Palais realizes every orbit for some orthogonal rep

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira's [referenced](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/414402/is-it-possible-to-realize-the-moebius-strip-as-a-linear-group-orbit#comment1062672_414425) question [Is the Moebius strip Riemannian homogeneous?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/410275/is-the-moebius-strip-riemannian-homogeneous) and @‍IanAgol's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/410275/is-the-moebius-strip-riemannian-homogeneous#comment1052835_410275).

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira:  Maybe you will be interested in this question: In David Speyer's example, $\mathrm{SE}(2)$ preserves a foliation on the Möbius strip $M$ by lines but no (pseudo-)Riemannian metric, while, in my example, $\mathrm{O}(2,1)$ preserves a pseudo-Riemannian metric on $M$ but no foliation.  These are both 3-dimensional groups, but $M$ can be written 'even more' homogeneously as $P/H$ where $P\subset \mathrm{GL}(3,\mathbb{R})$ has dimension 6 and $H$ has dimension $4$.  Is there a $P$-representation $\rho:P\to\mathrm{GL}(V)$ and a $v\in V$ whose $P$-stabilizer is $H$?

Comment: I'm just following up to say that the generalization I asked about in my previous comment is false. To see this consider the unit tangent bundle $ M $ of a surface $ \Sigma_g $ of genus $ g \geq 2 $. Then $ M \cong SL_2(\mathbb{R})/\pi_1(\Sigma_g) $ is pseudo Riemannian homogeneous because the Killing form of $ SL_2 $ has signature $ (2,1) $ and $ SL_2(\mathbb{R}) $ acts by isometries. But $ M $ cannot be a linear group orbit because the fundamental group is not virtually abelian (in fact it is not even virtually solvable since $  M $ admits $ \tilde{SL_2} $ geometry) .

Comment: Also I am interested in that question! I'll have to think about it more! The fact that any noncompact group mod a cocompact lattice is an example of a compact pseudo Riemannian homogeneous manifold is due to Ycor here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1947785/isometry-group-of-a-compact-pseudo-riemannian-manifold For the fact that a linear group orbit must have a virtually abelian fundamental group (indeed even stronger the fundamental group must have finite commutator subgroup) see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/206618/how-bad-can-pi-1-of-a-linear-group-orbit-be?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 19):

Here is another solution, using the special Euclidean group $\operatorname{SE}(2) := \operatorname{SO}(2) \ltimes \mathbb{R}^2$ instead of Robert Bryant's solution which uses $\operatorname{SO}(2,1)$.

Let $\operatorname{SE}(2)$ act on $\mathbb{R}^2$ in the usual way. Let $V$ be the vector space of (inhomogenous) polynomials of degree $\leq 2$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$, so $\operatorname{SE}(2)$ acts on $V$. Then the orbit of the polynomial $x^2$ is in bijection with the set of lines. (Namely, the zero locus of each such polynomial is a line, and, given a line $\ell$, the function $d(\ell,(x,y))^2$ is a quadratic polynomial in $(x,y)$.) So the orbit of $x^2$ is the space of lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$, which is a Mobius strip.

---

Here is the way I would think about this. Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and let $G$ be a group acting on $M$. Let $W$ be any finite dimensional subspace of $C^{\infty}(M)$. Then sending $x \in M$ to the "evaluation at $x$" gives a smooth map $M \to W^{\vee}$. If $W$ is $G$-invariant, then $W^{\vee}$ inherits a $G$-action and the map is $G$-equivariant. Unless we are very unlucky, the map is an embedding.

So I would start by thinking about a group $G$ acting on the Mobius strip $M$, take some function $f \in C^{\infty}(M)$ and see if the $G$-orbit of $f$ spans a finite dimensional vector space. That is how I found the above example, thinking about functions on the space of lines like "slope" and "distance from the origin", until I discovered that "square of distance to the origin" worked.

Comment: You might say, if the function $f$ is a polynomial and the Lie group acts as projective or affine transformations, as most that I can think of typically do, then clearly the degree of $f$ is preserved, so an orbit inside the finite dimensional vector space of polynomials of that degree.

Comment: In your construction, $V$ has dimension $6$, but that can be improved by noticing that your group preserves the 1-dimensional subspace of constant functions on the plane, so one can reduce to the $5$-dimensional quotient and still get a representation in which the orbit of $x^2$ is a Möbius strip.  Interestingly, this latter representation is reducible (unlike the $5$-dimensional representation that appears at the end in my construction), as it contains (the image of) the linear functions, but the orbit of $x^2$ in this reduced space is just a circle.

Comment: Wow this is also super interesting and I really appreciate you walking me through your thought process that is always the best part! Thank you for introducing the perspective of finite dimensional vector spaces of smooth functions ( side note: If I am not mistaken slope is not a well defined smooth function because of vertical lines?). I especially love @BenMcKay perspective about polynomials and how linear $ x \to ax+by $ and affine $ x \to ax+by+c $ transformations don't increase degree so naturally lead to finite dimensional representations on space of polynomials of bounded degree.